# How to reset a locked-out user's account

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

If a user enters the wrong password too many times (5 by default) then their account becomes locked and they are shown the following message:

[image: Max sign in error]

What do I, as an administrator, need to do to reset the account so that the user can log in again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset two field in the database in order to unlock the user's account. This can be done by running the following command on your SQL server:

```sql
update aspnet_Membership
set IsLockedOut=0, FailedPasswordAttemptCount=0
where UserId='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Where `UserId` is the GUID of the user whose account you want to unlock.

You could also use `where IsLockedOut=1` to reset all locked out accounts. I use this because you can't copy query results from within the Azure SQL Management Portal.

Answer (score 0):

Just resetting the password in the application also resets the log on count if that helps too.